# Simple df plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, ggplot2

I am a new user of R and I have a dataframe with three columns `car`,`var` and `val`. I have about 90 rows and I want to plot the two columns `var` and `val`. My data frame looks like

```
car  var  val

a     kl   -14
b     km   -1
c     kn   -3
d     ko   -20
```

I tried this `plot(data$var,data$val)` but I want to have something like this with X axis the var and Y axis the val. How can I do this with ggplot?
[image]

Comment: `ggplot(data, aes(x = var, y = val, group = 1)) +geom_line()`?

Comment: @RichardTelford  thank you!this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use a line to connect a categorical value unless it's ordinal. `geom_bar` is probably a better idea, e.g. `ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = val)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: @alistaire I have already tried this but my values are negative and the bars are "facing down"

Comment: As they should be; that's the values you have. I suppose you could transform them if it makes sense.

Comment: yes you are right. thank you for the geom_bar!

Comment: someone post something as an answer!

Comment: @RichardTelford please post a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a similar plot to the one you post using `geom_line`. You need to use the aesthetic `group = 1` because the x-axis data are discrete and each group has only a single observation.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
  car  var  val
  a     kl   -14
  b     km   -1
  c     kn   -3
  d     ko   -20
")

ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = val, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(colour = "green")
```

Given that the x-axis data are discrete, it probably makes more sense to use a `geom_bar` to get a bar plot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = val, group = 1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```